# How to split columns and plot a graph using facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

https://www.kaggle.com/shivamb/netflix-shows-and-movies-exploratory-analysis contains the data set. (2.13MB)

I am trying to split the country column from the netflix data set and plot a faceted bar plot representing Movies from three countries.

The reproducible code is as follws:-

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(lubridate)

netflix_tbl <- read.csv("netflix_titles_nov_2019.csv")

netflix_wrangled_tbl <- netflix_tbl%>%
    mutate(date_added = dmy(date_added), 
           date = day(date_added), month = month(date_added), year = year(date_added),
           count = readr::parse_number(as.character(duration)),
           show_type = stringr::str_remove(duration, as.character(count)))

netflix_wrangled_tbl %>%
    filter(type == "Movie") %>% 
    separate_rows(country, sep = ",")%>% 
    filter(country == "India" | country == "United States"| country == "United Kingdom")%>%
  separate_rows(cast, sep = ",")%>%
  # Count by country and cast
  count(country, cast)%>%
  slice_max(n, n = 24)%>%
  ggplot(aes(y = tidytext::reorder_within(cast, n, country), x = n))+
  geom_col() +
  tidytext::scale_y_reordered() +
  facet_wrap(~country, scales = "free")
```

The resultant output is,

[image]

The expected output is:-

[image]

May I know where I am going wrong and how to achieve the expected output? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying the last fragment of your code with this:

```
netflix_wrangled_tbl %>%
  filter(type == "Movie") %>% 
  separate_rows(country, sep = ",")%>% 
  filter(country == "India" | country == "United States"| country == "United Kingdom")%>%
  separate_rows(cast, sep = ",")%>%
  filter(cast!="") %>%
  # Count by country and cast
  count(country, cast)%>%
  group_by(country) %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  slice(seq_len(24)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = tidytext::reorder_within(cast, n, country), x = n))+
  geom_col() +
  tidytext::scale_y_reordered() +
  facet_wrap(~country, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: The code is working perfectly. Just wanted to seek clarification as to whether your output is correct or the one mentioned in the expected output is correct?

Comment: @SriSreshtan There are plenty of white spaces in `cast` that is why your code did not worked, and about the purple plot it depends on how many rows you want to show. Also that plot comes from python not `R`.

Comment: Agreed. Then why could there be a difference in the output?

Comment: It might be the number of top rows you choose. Also data is too old so be sure you have the same data as in those python notebook.